# Spring controller not getting called from EXTJS

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, extjs4.2

I am new to EXTJS. I want to create pie chart and the data for the pie chart I want to retrieve from database. Below is my code. Somehow controller is not getting called from EXTJS controller. Can somebody please help me on this. I am using EXTJS 4.2.

```
Ext.onReady(function() {
    Ext.define('DashBoard.model.DashBoardModel', {
        extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
        fields: ['title', 'size']
    });

Ext.define('DashBoard.store.DashBoardStore', {
        extend  : 'Ext.data.Store',
        model   : 'DashBoard.model.DashBoardModel',
        proxy   : {
            type    : 'ajax',
            url     : '/TechnologyPrortal/dashboard/loadDashBoard.action',
            reader  : {
                type    : 'json',
                root    : 'dashboarddetails'
            }
        }
      }); 

  var chart = Ext.create('Ext.chart.Chart', {
     renderTo: Ext.getBody(),
     xtype: 'chart',
     width: '100%',
     height: 410,
     padding: '10 0 0 0',
     style: 'background: #fff',
     animate: true,
     shadow: true,
     store: 'DashBoardStore',
     theme: 'Base:gradients',
     legend: {
            position: 'bottom'
        },
     series: [
     {
       type: 'pie',
       angleField: 'size',
       showInLegend: true,
       label: {
         field: 'title',
         display: 'outside',
         font: '12px Arial',
         calloutLine: true
       },
            highlight: {
                segment: {
                    margin: 20
                }
            },
            label: {
                field: 'title',
                display: 'rotate',
                contrast: true,
                font: '18px Arial'
            },
            tips: {
               trackMouse: true,
               width: 120,
               renderer: function(storeItem, item) {
               this.setTitle(storeItem.get('title') + ': ' + storeItem.get('size') + '%');
            }
          }
     }
    ]
  });   

   Ext.define('DashBoard.view.DashBoardView', {
  //var panel1 = Ext.create('widget.panel', {
  extend  : 'Ext.form.Panel',
        width: 800,
        height: 600,
        title: 'Server',
        alias   : 'widget.dashBoardView',
        renderTo: Ext.getBody(),
        layout: 'fit',
        tbar: [{
            text: 'Save Chart',
            handler: function() {
                Ext.MessageBox.confirm('Confirm Download', 'Would you like to download the chart as an image?', function(choice){
                    if(choice == 'yes'){
                        chart.save({
                            type: 'image/png'
                        });
                    }
                });
            }
        }],
        items: chart
    });

 Ext.define('DashBoard.controller.DashBoardDetails', {
    extend  : 'Ext.app.Controller',
    stores  : ['DashBoardStore'],
    views : ['DashBoardView'],
    refs:[
        {
            ref: 'dashBoardView',
            xtype : 'dashBoardView',
            selector: 'dashBoardView',
            autoCreate: true
        }
    ]

  });

Ext.application({
    name  : 'DashBoard',
    controllers: ['DashBoardDetails'],
      launch: function () {
        Ext.widget('dashBoardView', {
          width : '100%',
          height: 400,
          renderTo: 'output'
        });
      }
    }
  );
});
```

Thanks
Sachin

Comment: Can you show us the mapping on your controller as well as your web.xml?

Comment: I tried accessing the URL that worked fine. 'http://localhost:8080/TechnologyPrortal/dashboard/loadDashBoard.action'. Web.xml <servlet>
  <servlet-name>TechnologyPrortal</servlet-name>
  <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
 <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
 </servlet>
 <servlet-mapping>
  <servlet-name>TechnologyPrortal</servlet-name>
  <url-pattern>*.action</url-pattern>
 </servlet-mapping>

Comment: I have resolved this issue. There is a problem in my EXTJS controller code. Thanks